# Is there a way to send Google Apps email from within my gmail.com account without having it say mailed-by gmail.com?

Tags: smtp, g-suite, gmail

I like working from my main gmail account for everything. My company uses google apps. I've enabled my gmail to send emails on behalf of my work email, and it does this, but in the mailed-by field it has my gmail address. I think this looks unprofessional to recipients, so I want to be able to send email without this field showing gmail.com. Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: ...or the webapps stackexchange site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Google Apps serve as "external" smtp server. Follow the steps in [this document](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=22370) and follow the "If you choose to send mail through another domain's SMTP servers" path.